# Passing object informations to an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure this out. I have created a menu and a Scanner to get the variables. Now I want each object to be stored in an array with their own information. But my code is not working the way I want.

```
package com.Adams;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner vehicle = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your auctionId ");
        String auctionId = vehicle.nextLine() ;
        System.out.println("Enter the vehicule description");
        String vehicleDescription = vehicle.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the reserve price");
        int resevePrice = vehicle.nextInt();

        VehiculeAuction newVehicle = new VehiculeAuction(auctionId,      vehicleDescription, resevePrice );



        //  Define an array of VehicleAuction references named auctions,
        // which can be used to store up to 20 VehicleAuction objects.

        VehiculeAuction auctions[] = new VehiculeAuction[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < auctions.length; i ++) {
            auctions[i] = new VehiculeAuction("", "", 0);
            System.out.println(auctions[i]);
        }

        int auctionCount = 0;
        do {
            auctionCount++;

            System.out.printf("***** Auction System Menu *****");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "A. " + "Add New Vehicle Auction");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "B. " + "Display All Vehicle Auctions");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "C. " + "Submit Bid for Vehicle");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "D. " + "List Ended Vehicle Auctions");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "X. " + "Exit the program");
            System.out.printf("%n" + "Enter your selection: ");

            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            String selection = console.nextLine();

            switch (selection.toUpperCase()) {
                case "A": {
                    System.out.println("testA");
                    break;
                }
                case "B": {
                    System.out.println("testB");
                    //Display all vehicle auctions
                    break;
                }
                case "C": {
                    System.out.println("testC");
                    //Submit Bid for Vehicle
                    break;
                }
                case "D": {
                    System.out.println("testD");
                    //List ended vehicle auctions
                    break;
                }
                case "X": {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                default:
                    System.out.printf("That is not a valid response. Try Again.");
            }
        } while (auctionCount <= 20);

        System.out.println(auctionCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us how you want it to work before we can help you figure out why it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok sorry this is the first time I ask a question sorry. I have a menu at the top but it's working the way i want no issues there, but what I want is to prompt the user to enter all details , when those details are entered through the Scanner , then a new object is created, in the Vehicle class  with those information. Then I want the auctions array to store those informations in each index like : auction[0] "auctionID, "VehiculDescription , reserveprice". And if someone else put another auction on the vehicle , I want it to be stored in index 2 up to 20, then I can't take anymore auctions.

Comment: If the user ID (auctionID) matches a previously used auction then I only want to store the data instead of storing it in a new index. Sorry i'm french hopefully I explained myself well enough. Cheers

Comment: Edit your question, don't put everything in the comments. Perhaps you should [Take a Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Don't be too hard , it's just my first questions guys. You know people learn as they go. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three observations:

1. You have a block of code at the top which asks for auction ID and vehicle info.  Why is it there?  Shouldn't it be part of the processing for  `case "A":` below?
2. The line `auctionCount++` at the top of the `do...while` loop:  why is it there?  If `auctionCount` truly is an **auction count**, you only want to increment it when you *actually add an auction* to your list, yes?  That should only happen as part of the processing in `case "A":`, I think.   As things are, `auctionCount` is just counting the number of times you ask the user to enter a menu option.
3. Multiple `Scanner`s on `System.in`:  you should create just one and use it every time you need input.  Each `Scanner` expects that it is the *only* one reading from the input, and several `Scanner`s trying to read the same input source will "confuse" each other.

Aside from these issues, it looks like you have a reasonably good start.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I figured out my issue, I only wanted to put each object created into the array, I think this is the code I needed .

Comment: VehiculeAuction auctions[] = new VehiculeAuction[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < auctions.length ; i++){

            auctions[i] = new VehiculeAuction(auctionId,vehicleDescription, resevePrice);
        }


        int auctionCount = 0;

Comment: I will change the Scanner thing and make it better thank you

Comment: People are so angry here, I'm trying my best but they did everything to stop me from posting, why are you so angry . We are all trying our best .